# Trying to get property of non-object while trying to run cronjob and generate user profit

Tags: laravel

can someone help, i need to run cron job but every time i try to run it generates  the error
"Trying to get property of non-object"

here is my controller

```js
public
function repeatGenerate() {
  $basic = BasicSetting::first();
  if ($basic - > repeat_status == 1) {

    $repeats = Repeat::whereStatus(0) - > get();
    foreach($repeats as $rep) {
      if ($rep - > repeat_time < Carbon::now()) {

        $rLog['user_id'] = $rep - > user_id;
        $rLog['trx_id'] = strtoupper(Str::random(20));
        $rLog['investment_id'] = $rep - > investment_id;
        $rLog['made_time'] = Carbon::now();
        $rLog['amount'] = round(($rep - > invest - > amount * $rep - > invest - > plan - > percent) / 100, $basic - > deci);
        RepeatLog::create($rLog);

        $rep - > total_repeat = $rep - > total_repeat + 1;
        $rep - > made_time = Carbon::now();
        $rep - > repeat_time = Carbon::parse() - > addHours($rep - > invest - > plan - > compound - > compound);
        if ($rep - > total_repeat == $rep - > invest - > plan - > time) {
          $rep - > status = 1;
          $inv = Investment::findOrFail($rep - > investment_id);
          $inv - > status = 1;
          $inv - > save();
        }

   

 
     

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your cronjob look like, i.e. how is this script invoked?

Comment: Which line is throwing that error? What's your "non-object" ?

Comment: $rLog['amount'] = round(($rep->invest->amount * $rep->invest->plan->percent) / 100,$basic->deci);